# Method to dynamically build large dataframe (spark or pandas) for export to csv

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a csv that I import into databricks using spark.read.  This large file contains records/transactions on a daily level.  I trim the dataframe down to 5 columns and leave the 500,000 rows as-is.  I am trying to build a summary table of this source file that represents these records/transactions at a month level (aggregate).

The script has a filter/groupby/sum command that returns one row that summarizes the data into counts for a month.  A row that is returned by the query would look like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
|  Country|StockCode|YYYY-MM|sum(Quantity)|
+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
|Singapore|        M| 2011-4|           10|
+---------+---------+-------+-------------+
```

the script iterates over the source dataframe and returns each time.  I am having the trouble being able to use the output (display or csv export) of this script.  Both in pyspark and pandas I have problems.  I'm not sure how to stack the result of the query and what form it should be in?

#Pandas
If I do it in pandas, the script takes very long to generate the file (I believe pandas + me doing it not so efficiently is causing the extended duration) ~ 2.5 hours.  The display and write.csv commands works rather quickly though and complete in approx a few seconds.

#Pyspark
If I do this in pyspark the script takes about 10 minutes to complete, but the display and the export crash.  The notebook either returns a timeout error, restarts or throws crash errors.

Should the approach be to create a list of lists dynamically, and when that is completely built, convert that to a dataframe for use?  I've been trying all the ways I have come across and I seem to not make any progress.

Here is the code that generates the results

```
#officeSummaryDFBefore
column_names = "Country|StockCode|YYYY-MM|Quantity"
monthlyCountsBeforeImpactDate = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    tuple('' for i in column_names.split("|"))
  ],
  column_names.split("|")
).where("1=0")

monthlyCountsBeforeImpacteDateRow = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    tuple('' for i in column_names.split("|"))
  ],
  column_names.split("|")
).where("1=0")

try :
  for country in country_lookup :
    country = country[0]
    print(country_count, " country(s) left")
    country_count = country_count - 1
    for stockCode in stockCode_lookup :
      stockCode = stockCode[0]
      monthlyCountsBeforeImpacteDateRow = dataBeforeImpactDate.filter((col("Country").rlike(country)) & (col("StockCode").rlike(stockCode))).groupby("Country", "StockCode", "YYYY-MM").sum()
      monthlyCountsBeforeImpacteDateRow.show()
      dfsCountsBefore = [monthlyCountsBeforeImpacteDateRow, monthlyCountsBeforeImpactDate]
      monthlyCountsBeforeImpactDate = reduce(DataFrame.union, dfsCountsBefore)
      
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

I declare dfsCountsBeforeImpactDate inside the loop which doesn't seem right, but when it is outside it comes back as NULL.

Comment: You may consider to provide more memory for your systems: a) Provide more physical memory, b) `del` variables which are no longer used, c) Do you really need 500,000 rows of data to get the summary; d) Could you generate multiple summary rows and then obtain a summary of summaries?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC
You are doing a lookup on country and stock to restrict the rows then grouping over them to generate the aggregations.

Why not filter the df's altogether then grouping

```
df = dataBeforeImpactDate

df = df.filter(col('country').isin(country_lookup) & col('stock').isin(stock_lookup))

df = df.groupby("Country", "StockCode", "YYYY-MM").sum()

df.show()
```

This will be way faster as you are not looping around for filter and also no need of union.

Comment: let me try what you are saying.  Thanks for helping out!